# Why do anonymous classes not implement System.IEquatable<T>?

Tags: c#, equality, anonymous-types, anonymous-class

Anonymous classes (a.k.a. anonymous types) are implicitly created and used by the C# compiler for code like this:

```
var obj = new { X1 = 0, X2 = 1 };
```

They have value equality semantics, i.e., the method `bool Equals(object? obj)` from the class `object` is overridden to perform field-by-field comparison. A typical C# class or struct `T` with value equality semantics implements the interface `System.IEquatable<T>`. The [official guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type) for how to implement equality also asserts that "both classes and structs require the same basic steps for implementing equality:

1. Override the `virtual Object.Equals(Object)` method. In most cases, your implementation of `bool Equals(object obj)` should just call into the type-specific `Equals` method that is the implementation of the `System.IEquatable<T>` interface. (See step 2.)
2. Implement the `System.IEquatable<T>` interface by providing a type-specific `Equals` method."

However, anonymous classes are compiled to something like this:

```
internal sealed class AnonymousType<T1, T2> {
    public T1 X1 { get; }
    public T2 X2 { get; }

    public AnonymousType(T1 x1, T2 x2) { X1 = x1; X2 = x2; }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj) {
        var other = obj as AnonymousType<T1, T2>;
        return this == other || (other != null &&
            EqualityComparer<T1>.Default.Equals(X1, other.X1) && 
            EqualityComparer<T2>.Default.Equals(X2, other.X2));
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() { /* code omitted */ }
    public override string ToString() { /* code omitted */ }
}
```

I would expect them to look more like this instead:

```
internal sealed class AnonymousType<T1, T2> : IEquatable<AnonymousType<T1, T2>> {
    public T1 X1 { get; }
    public T2 X2 { get; }

    public AnonymousType(T1 x1, T2 x2) { X1 = x1; X2 = x2; }

    public bool Equals(AnonymousType<T1, T2>? other) =>
        this == other || (other != null &&
        EqualityComparer<T1>.Default.Equals(X1, other.X1) && 
        EqualityComparer<T2>.Default.Equals(X2, other.X2));

    public override bool Equals(object? obj) =>
        Equals(obj as AnonymousType<T1, T2>);
    public override int GetHashCode() { /* code omitted */ }
    public override string ToString() { /* code omitted */ }
}
```

Perhaps, I would also add the `==` and `!=` operators. (The guidelines say this is "optional but recommended".)

Is there any specific reason why anonymous classes do not implement `IEquatable<T>`, breaking the aforementioned guidelines?

Comment: In practical terms: the way it is, does just the same as if it would implement the interface. So where's the point, except that these early lightweight-pocos of .NET do not fully comply with guidelines designed for non-anonymous types?